# не могу понять какая ошибка в коде JS

Tags: javascript, html5

```
var next = document.getElementsByClassName("next1");
next.addEventListener("click", function(){
alert("hello");
});
```

при запуске браузер ругается:
script.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: next.addEventListener is not a function
at script.js:8

подскажите что тут не так?

Comment: `next[0].addEvent...`

Comment: добавил 0 все равно тоже самое!

Comment: @Юрий Нет, ошибка стала другой. ("то же" здесь пишется раздельно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//  навешиваем обработчики клика после события загрузки страницы,
// иначе скрипт может не найти элементы, на которые нужно повесить клики
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  console.log('load');
  // находим все элементы с классом next1, 
  // преобразуем в массив и кладем в переменную 
  var next = [...document.getElementsByClassName("next1")];
  //на каждый элемент из массива навешиваем клик
  next.forEach(i => i.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("hello");
  }));
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="next1">Button</button>
<button type="button" class="next1">Button</button>
<button type="button" class="next1">Button</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо но я тут щас теперь разобраться не могу что к чему!))) можешь немного пояснить что добавил? если не трудно! А то я только учусь мне пока сложно читать код с новыми элементами!!

Comment: @Юрий обновлено

Comment: Тем не менее, вопрос был "что тут не так", а не "как сделать АВС" ;-)